# How to hint Google Smart Lock to use a specific input field as the username in a website

Tags: html, google-api, google-smartlockpasswords

I've been trying to search for some documentation on how to hint Google Smart Lock for Chrome to use a specific input field as the one associated with the username without any luck.

For the password it works perfectly as it is using `type="password"` but when it comes down to the username in a multi field form, where the username is not specified before the password or not as the first field in the form it picks another of the fields in the form as the username.

Does anyone have any clue on how to hint Google Smart Lock to use a specific input field as the username?

Answer (score 8):

Google smart lock is a build-in feature of chrome, there is the same function on firefox. It based on the last input type="password" to detect password field would be saved.
Here are some things I have tested on FireFox and Chrome

1. Chrome:

   - Based on the last input type password (you even have more than 2 input password elements)
   - If 2 last input type password has the same value -> decide to save **password**
   - Look up to find an upper input type text from the first input type password (**Not** a **hidden** type nor **disabled**) to pick it as **username**
2. Firefox:

   - Based on the last input type password (you even have more than 2 input password elements)
   - If 2 last input type password has the same value -> decide to save **password**
   - Look up to find an upper input type text from the first input type password (**Not** a **hidden** type) to pick it as **username**, note that FF allow input disabled is an username :)

Comment: Do you know of a way to include a hidden user name? I have a situation where when a user first sets his password we already have his username so the form doesn't ask for it. As a result browsers are interpreting an unrelated field as the username. I tried using a hidden field before finding your response. I'm short on ideas!

Comment: @Julian you could try hiding the field with display: none; This is the only way that seemed to work for me. Changing the input type to a hidden field with autocomplete="username" did not work from my testing.

Comment: @JoelDuckworth it doesn't work if there is another active input field above. Consider this flow: active input field > display none username field > 1st password field > 2nd password field.

Comment: @Jun why not just put the username field at the top then? Since it's hidden it doesn't make any difference. Or am I missing something...

Comment: @JoelDuckworth Google Smart Lock will look for an active input field if there is one. so, it will ignore the hidden username even if you put it right before the password or at the top.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to put:

```
autocomplete="username"
```

on the required field (usually the user's email, or site's user name).

then it will know to use it as the key to the smartlock feature (tested on chrome).

Comment: I have tried this and it didn't seem to work with an input type="hidden"

Comment: I can confirm that this works with Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: none` css to hide a username input. The following code snippet is taken from [Chromium design document](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/form-styles-that-chromium-understands). They discuss a few use cases there.

```
<style>
  #emailfield { display: none; }
</style>
<form id="login" action="login.php" method="post">
  <input id="emailfield" type="text" value="me@example.test" autocomplete="username">
  <input type="password" autocomplete="current-password">
  <input type="submit" value="Sign In!">
</form>
```

Check out [this article](https://www.language-diary.com/2018/09/hint-browsers-username-password-input.html) that explains how to make it work on Chrome, Firefox and Safari for 3 different cases: normal login, username first login and reset password page with verification input first.

I have also made a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/jun711/pen/oPVzgG) where you can try it out.